# Overwriting nodeid when allocating nodeid++ in 2D array while moving

Tags: c, arrays, overwrite

I'm trying to allocate updated nodeid values to new array elements, but everytime I do so, I overwrite my nodeid value with the initial value of the array element in which I allocate nodeid. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "motion.h"

int motion (int nodeid, int row, int column, int direction) {

    nodeid = field [row][column];

    while (((row < (LENGTH - 1))&&(row > 0))||((column < (WIDTH - 1))&&(column > 0))){
        if (direction == 0){
            nodeid++;

            nodeid = field [row][column + 1];
            column++;
        }
        else if (direction == 1){
            nodeid++;
            nodeid = field [row][column - 1];
            column--;
        }
        else if (direction == 2) {
            nodeid++;
            nodeid = field [row - 1][column];
            row--;
        }
        else if (direction == 3) {
            nodeid++;
            nodeid = field [row + 1][column];
            row++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here's my custom header file, motion.h:

```
#define LENGTH 18
#define WIDTH 12
#define SAMPLES 8
enum direction {Right, Left, Up, Down};
int field [LENGTH][WIDTH];
int column;
int row;
int nodeid;
int direction;
int motion (int nodeid, int row, int column, int direction);
int print_field (int field[][ WIDTH ], int row, int column);
```

and my source code, main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "motion.h"

int main() {

int samples;
int i;
int j;
int k;

printf ("How many samples do you want?\n");
scanf ("%d", &samples);

for (i = 0; i < samples; i++){
       printf ("Indicate nodeid, row, column and direction\n");
       scanf ("%d %d %d %d", &nodeid, &row, &column, &direction);
for(j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
{
       for(k = 0; k < WIDTH; k++){
       field[j][k] = 0;
}
}
motion (nodeid, row, column, direction);
printf ("\n%d", print_field(field, row, column));
}

return 0;
}
~
```

As you can see, code such as nodeid = field [row][column + 1] overwrites nodeid++ (according to my knowledge). How do I properly allocate nodeid without overwriting it?

UPDATE: Good news and bad news. Good news is that it displays my answers now. Bad news:

```
Indicate nodeid, row, column and direction
_____________________________
|0.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.000|
|0.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.000|
|0.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.000|
_____________________________
```

As you can see, all of my results are 0 inside the bar along with dots here and there.

This is the code for my print_Field function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "motion.h"

int print_field(int field[][ WIDTH ], int row, int column){

int i;
int j;
int k;
int t;

for ( k = 0; k < WIDTH * 6; k++){
    printf("_");
}

printf ("\n");

for ( i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
printf ("|");

for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
printf( "%.3f", field [i][j]) ;
printf (" ");
}

printf ("\n");

for ( i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
printf ("|");

for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
printf( "%.3f", field [i][j]) ;
printf (" ");
}
printf ("\b|");
printf ("\n");
}
for (t = 0; t < WIDTH * 6; t++){

printf("_");
}
printf ("\n");
return 0;
}
```

After much tinkering, I got this:

```
 ________________________________________________________________________

 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 |0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000|
 ________________________________________________________________________
```

Apparently, there's still something iin my motion.c code that's preventing the non-zero numbers from displaying.

Comment: I am getting fed up with typing this "indent to make it readable"

Comment: @EdHeal: Indented it, should be accepted soon :P

Comment: i don't see the code where the field variable is allocated.constructed

Comment: You don't need any of those parens inside the while condition.

Comment: Sorry, but I just got started using C, and indenting it correctly is a pain. But let's focus on the problem right now. Can you help me?

Comment: Will add that right now.

Comment: Personally, I cannot understand what you're trying to do. You increment the int nodeid, and then you assign another value to it. Why?

Comment: I'm trying to move the nodeid to another position in the array. But it always overwrites it. How can I move it without overwriting it?

Comment: So let's say I have this:

0 0 1 0

And I want to move it left, after incrementing it. This is what I want:

0 2 1 0.

How do I do that?

Comment: field is an array of integers, but you're trying to print them as floats in your printf. Use %d instead of %f.

Comment: My assignment requires me to print 3 decimal digits for each integer element of field. Where should I make the switch?

Comment: You could do this, but it seems kind of weird: `printf("%.3f", (double)field[i][j]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your assignment backwards. Instead of

```
 nodeid = field [row][column + 1];
```

try

```
 field [row][column + 1] = nodeid;
```

Also, you should use your enumeration constants (Right, Left, etc.) in your motion function.
And you should define column, row, nodeid, and direction inside main, not globably.

So, I'd rewrite it like this:

```
int motion (int nodeid, int row, int column, int direction) {

    field [row][column] = nodeid;

    while (row < LENGTH - 1 && row > 0 && column < WIDTH - 1 && column > 0){
        if (direction == Right)
            field[row][++column] = ++nodeid;
        else if (direction == Left)
            field[row][--column] = ++nodeid;
        else if (direction == Up)
            field[--row][column] = ++nodeid;
        else if (direction == Down)
            field[++row][column] = ++nodeid;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I still get segmentation fault (core dumped) and when I try to access gdb, I get this:

    gdb: symbol lookup error: gdb: undefined symbol:                PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject

Comment: The || in the while condition should have been &&. I changed it.